# CakePHP 3: Validate Form

Tags: validation, cakephp

I need to validate a form and I don't know exactly how I can do this. I tried to validate it in Model/Users.php and Model/Table/UserTables.php and it did not work.

Can someone help me?

**register.ctp**

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-4  large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Cadastro</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>

            <?= $this->Form->input('nome'); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('email'); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password'); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->submit('Cadastrar', array('class' => 'button')); ?>


        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know exaclty where I can put this:

```
public $validate = array(
   //campo que deve ser validado
   ‘nome’ => array(
      //alias da validação
      ‘notempty’ => array(  
    ‘rule’=>’notempty’,//validação para não aceitar vazio
    ‘message’=>”Você deve preencher este campo”//erro
      )
   ),
   ‘idade’ => array(
    ‘notempty’ => array(
    ‘rule’ => ‘notempty’,
    ‘message’ => ‘Você deve preencher este campo’
   ),
   ‘numeric’ => array(
    ‘rule’ => ‘numeric’,
    ‘message’ => ‘Você deve preencher este campo’
   )
 )
 );
}
```

validation on **UsersTable.php** only works with "add" form:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('nome', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('nome');

        $validator
            ->email('email')
            ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('email');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('password');



        return $validator;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put the validation in the model.  It looks like you are using the validation syntax for cakephp 2, but your title says you are using version 3.  You can see that here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#simple-rules

Here are the docs for cakephp 3 validation: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html

You'll need to add this to the model

```
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

$validator = new Validator();
```

and from there you can add things like

```
$validator->notEmpty('title', 'Please fill this field')
```

Comment: I put this on Model/Entity/User.php folder? Thanks for answer.

Comment: You'll want to add it to the model where you are saving.  So add it to the User model if you are saving to the users table.

Comment: I can't validate. the "add" form has validation working but my register form doesn't works validation. I'm new on CakePHP.

Comment: Model validation is imposed whenever you attempt a save to the corresponding table.  So the validation should work regardless of what form you are using to save.  What model is the add form saving to, and what model is the register form saving to?  Could you post the code and the validation that is working for add?

Comment: I edited the post and uploaded the validation code located on UserTables.php.